# How to use variable instead of function name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to know whether there is a method to use variable name instead of function.
That is,

```
function dialog(a,b) {
    a(b);
}
```

Example: If user pass `'alert'` to `a` and the content to `b`.
Then it should alert `b`.

If `a` is `'confirm'`, then it should confirm `b`.

I can use switch case or if else, but I would like to know the above is possible.

Comment: Oh, oh. I misread your question. Mods: Please disregard the flag.

Comment: Are you passing the strings `'alert'`, and `'confirm'`, or the functions `alert` and `confirm`?  The latter works fine - i.e. `dialog(alert, 'hello world')` alerts and `confirm` works as well.  I most definitely would not use the `eval` solution.

Comment: Another option is `dialog('alert','Hello World')` and `window[a](b);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.call()`

```
function callme(a,b){
  return a.call(null, b);
};

var func = function(c) {
  return c;
};

alert(callme(func, "test"));
```

Any function you pass to `callme` will execute there. The first argument is the context, so you could pass `this` if you need to. Pass `null` otherwise.

In your case, alert/confirm can be passed. If you don't need to return something, just do an empty return at the end.

Don't use `eval`, for the love of all things good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`eval()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), however it can lead to [insecurities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!) if you aren't careful.

You *could* just have the users supply them the function itself if, in your example, they passed in the raw function as `a`, but I'm assuming you want them to pass a string which names a function that gets used.

```
function(a, b) {
  eval(a + '(' + b + ')');
}
```

Comment: @caasjj Um... other than it doesn't exist?  If you can refer me to an MDN article or some other type of documentation, I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: Sorry, what doesn't exist?  He's defining the function `dialog`, `alert` is a global and the other parameter is a string. BTW, your solution is a Javascript syntax error :)

Comment: @caasjj Ahh, I see what you mean now.  Yes, if he passes in a raw JS function, you can call it like that.